# Predicting outcome of binary data

Tags: time-series, prediction, binary-data

I have a time series data structure in the form:
$$  
  \stackrel{\mbox{Time $t$}}{%
   \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & p_{t} & p_{t+1}
\end{bmatrix}}\
$$

where each entry is a binary result for some task, I would like to know if it is possible to predict the probability that the next outcome p_t is correct. The assumption regarding the data that is made is that the user performance in the task increases over time and then stabilizes to some value.

Thanks,

Sagar

Answer (score 1):

You could just fit a model like $p(t) = a+b*(1-exp(-ct))$ to the $(t,p_t)$ pairs, using a least-squares approach for example.

Comment: Hi could you point toward any resources online?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Fd4ukzkxps

Comment: http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/leastsquares.asp

Comment: Will this work using binary data?

Comment: Yes it will. It will look different to the example. Alternatively you could work with the cumulative data and a cumulative model.

Comment: The equivalent cumulative model is $p(t)=at+b(exp(-ct)-1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, I have implemented a working solution using Logistic Regression with time and lag values as my covariates

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for this information, I learned about Logistic Regression and Likelihood-ratio Test --- the latter is relevant to my current work.